# Wordpress Docker container can't connect to database container

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to migrate a worpdress site to a docker container for local development.

However every time I use docker compose I keep getting this:

> MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'root'@'172.22.0.3'

I've double checked the passwords and validated them via shell on the db container.

Here is my `docker-compose` file:

```
services: # configuring each container
db: # name of our mysql container
image: mysql:5.7 # which image to pull, in this case specifying v. 5.7
volumes: # data to map to the container
  - ./data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d # where to find our data - we'll talk more about this
restart: always # always restart the container after reboot
environment: # environment variables -- mysql options in this case
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: *****
  MYSQL_DATABASE: **_***
  MYSQL_USER: *****
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: *****

....
wordpress:
    depends_on: # container dependencies that need to be running first
  - db
  image: wordpress:latest # image used by our container
   ports:
  - "8080:80" # setting our ports for networking
   restart: always
   environment:
     WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306 # default mysql port
     WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: **** # matches $MYSQL_PASSWORD
   volumes: # this is where we tell Docker what to pay attention to
  - ./wp-content/themes/chronus:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/chronus # mapping our custom theme to the container
  - ./wp-content/plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins # map our plugins to the container
  - ./wp-content/uploads:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads # map our uploads to the container
```

Comment: It seems some part of your compose file were left out? Could you pls provide them (e.g. which image is used for the wordpress service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the official [Wordpress image](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) from docker hub. You have specifified the `WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD` flag but not the `WORDPRESS_DB_USER`. That means, the wordpress plugin is defaulting to `root`.

However, as per your comments, you entered the the password for some arbitrary user here (not the root user).

Modify the wordpress containers' environment variables as follows in your compose file and it should work:

```
   environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306 # default mysql port
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: **** # matches $MYSQL_PASSWORD
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: **** # matches $MYSQL_USER
```

Comment: Sorry forgot that!